# show data in lightbox

Tags: php, javascript

[image]

i want to show related data on click red circled image in light box but when i click it always shows the data in light box of the first record in the table i want to show concern record of click ,my code is here in JavaScript i have write these lines of code

```
 <script>
 function manageLightbox(visibility,id) {
 document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = visibility;
 document.getElementById('content').style.display = visibility;
 }
 </script>
```

i have called this function in my html

```
<a href="#"><img src="images/core/icon16/zoom.png" title="View" onClick="return manageLightbox('block','<?php echo $res['id']?>');" /></a>
```

the html of my light box is just here

```
<div id="content" class="content">
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onClick="return manageLightbox('none')">
<img  src="images/images1.jpeg" style="width:25px; height:25px; float:right"/></a>
<br/>
<center>
    <table>
        <tr>
           <td>Product_ID</td>
           <td><input type="text" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>"/></td>
        </tr>
      //and all other fields in light box ....
    </table>
</center>
</div>
<div id="overlay" class="overlay" onClick="return manageLightbox("")></div>
```

Comment: have you pass any link on red circled image when click ?

Comment: on click i passed the id '<?php echo $res['id']?>'

Comment: you got id inside function manageLightbox ?

Comment: can any one help me to sort out this

Comment: if you wont provide the answer close the question.
also you have an issue with your quotes here `<div id="overlay" class="overlay" onClick="return manageLightbox("")></div>` should maybe be something like `onClick="return manageLightbox('')"`

Answer (score 1):

First, you are using $res in your call, and $row in your view, maybe wrong name?
Second, do you use AJAX? With Jquery you can make easy AJAX calls and put the data into a place where you want.
So:
Use the $res["id"] as data to the data you want, (return for example the table) and include that in your div content.

The reason why you see only the first is because you assign multiple div's with the same name, javascript will return the first element with the given name. By using AJAX you can make a call, and the information will be included in the only div "content" which you have on your view.

Example:

```
<script>
$(".link_zoom").click(function(){ //add class to a href: class='link_zoom', when click, trigger event
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST'
      url: "someaction.do.php",
      data: "id=" + $(this).attr("id"), //add to the a href: id='<?php echo $res["id"]; ?>'
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(html) 
      { 
        $(".content").html(html); //will add the html to the content div
      }
   });
});
</script>
```